making a DF96 pentode crystal oscillator
I want to make a crystal oscillator using DF96 vacuum tube. The tube is a small RF/IF amplifier for battery operated systems. This tube is unique in the sense that it only takes 25ma of filament current. Very low power tube. I can easily use transistors, but I want to use the tube out of pure nostalgia. I have found a oscillator in internet but that is a VFO and not a crystal oscillator. I am sharing it here as a reference. Can we take this circuit and modify it to work as crystal oscillator. I am also OK if i need to make the circuit from scratch. Need some guidance please. I have also given snapshot from tube datasheet and link.
The reference oscillator circuit
DF96 Datasheet




Do you know how to make a pentode amplifier?

If you say that can I bias a pentode for small signal amplification by looking at datasheet ? Yes.

Then add the crystal and requisite loading capacitors and you should be good to go. Of course you have to ensure you don't overdrive the crystal with your anode signal = that's why we try and run xtal oscillators on 5 volts or less.
